# Remove initial background-color first md-button in menu

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS and Material Design for my application. In the app I have a `md-menu` element:

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" md-offset="0 42">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button rounded dtp-btn-ok" ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event);">
        <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content class="person-popup contact-popup">
        <md-card md-theme-watch>
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Headline</span>
                    <span class="md-subhead">Subhead informatie</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                </md-button>
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                </md-button>
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons">forward</i>
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Material Design sets a color on the background of the first button inside the menu. This is also how they do it in their demo > https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu.

I would like to either remove this or override it.

Adding:

```
.md-button {
    background-color: #fff!important;
}
```

To the root of my css doesn't work. So I think the css is being overwritten. But I can't check the CSS selector for the initial state of the button (the one with the Material color background) because as soon as I pauze the browser (F8) the background-color is removed.

Anyone got some experience with this?

// EDIT //

Working with the basic codepen AngularJS/Material Design I've recreated my situation. And it seems to work in there with the same code.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmQNzv

So it looks like I have a CSS problem in my own code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This seems working on the website: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

```
.md-button:first-child {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Alternatively you can try using higher specificity to override even further:

```
md-card-actions>.md-button:first-child {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Material Design adds a `md-focus` class to the first `md-button` in a `md-menu`.

This directive should work:

```
.directive('mdPreventFocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, $mdOpenMenu) {
            scope.$on('$mdMenuOpen', function(ev, element) {
                const interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('md-clickable').length > 0 && document.getElementsByClassName('md-clickable')[0].querySelector('.md-focused')) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('md-clickable')[0].querySelector('.md-focused').classList.remove('md-focused');
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 5);
            });
        }
    }
})
```